# Why links don't work in jsp when added tabs css?

Tags: css, jsp, spring-mvc, tabs

I have added some css to implement tabs in my jsp page (with using spring mvc).
It has to work just in Chrome, it is not important to customise to other browsers

Here is my css :

```
.w3c {
    min-height: 450px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.w3c > div { display: inline; }
.w3c > div > a { margin-left: -1px; position: relative; left: 1px; text-decoration: none; color: black; background: transparent; display: block; float: left; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-bottom: 1px solid white; }
.w3c > div:not(:target) > a { border-bottom: 0; background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #eee); }
.w3c > div:target > a { background: #ffffff; }
.w3c > div > div { background: #ffffff; z-index: -2; left: 0; top: 30px; bottom: 0; right: 0; padding: 20px; border: 1px solid #ccc; }
.w3c > div:not(:target) > div { position: absolute }
.w3c > div:target > div { position: absolute; z-index: -1; }
```

And part of jsp page

```
   <div style="width: 90%; float: left;">
        <div class="w3c">
            <div id="tab1">
                <a href="#tab1">Список предметів</a>

                <div>
                    <c:if test="${not empty foundData.subjects}">
                    <form>
                        <c:forEach items="${foundData.subjects}" var="subject">
                            <c:url value="/profileSubject.do" var="profileUrl">
                                <c:param name="selectedSubject" value="${subject.idSubject}"/>
                            </c:url>
                            <a name="selected" href="${profileUrl}"/><c:out value="${subject.nameSubject}"/></a> </br>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </form>
                    </c:if>

                    <c:if test="${empty foundData.subjects}">
                        <c:out value="Немає даних про предмети"/>
                    </c:if>

                    <form action="/timetable/profileSubject.do" method="get">
                        <input type="submit" value="Додати"/>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

            <%--Group--%>
            <div id="tab2">
                <a href="#tab2">Список груп</a>

                <div>... and so on
```

Without styles all links and buttons work properly, but when I add css styles - everything doesn't work.

Please, help me to find solution to this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this issue. Problem was with z-index, it takes the negative value.
When I have changed z-index: -2 to z-index: 1 and z-index: -1 to z-index: 2 - all seems to work well.